# Migrate from POP to IMAP on Gmail without duplicating emails and preserving local folder structure

Tags: email, thunderbird, gmail, imap

We are on G Suite and have one user who is still on POP and has lots of folders and locally stored emails in Thunderbird. I want to migrate them to IMAP and I'm fine with recreating all the labels and folders manually.  However, how do I move/label all the messages in those folders into the new IMAP structure without duplicating all the messages?

I was intending to just copy the emails from the Thunderbird local folders up into the IMAP folder structure, but I suspect that will end up with duplicate emails.

Is there any way to avoid this or a simple way to de-duplicate after it's done? I don't want to delete messages in the current accounts All Mail folder and I don't want to use a new empty account.

Comment: How you accomplish this depends on if the email was downloaded then deleted or just downloaded. If it was just downloaded then just transition to IMAP as all the emails will presumably be downloaded over IMAP

Comment: Everything was downloaded and then organized into folders. Nothing was deleted. So we don’t want to lose all the emails organized by folder if possible.  But if we move them from Thunderbird’s local folders into the IMAP folders, they will be duplicated, right? That’s what we want to avoid.

Comment: …*depends on if the email was downloaded then deleted* from the servers. POP uses manual or automatic deletion rules, often initiated at the client - https://i.stack.imgur.com/TYnap.png - but it can also be initiated at the server, depending on how it's set up. Before worrying about duplication, check the server to see what's actually there. Also warn your user that with IMAP, any mail they delete from any instance will delete all. Someone still on POP may be unaware of that.

Comment: @Tetsujin - already know what's there...this gmail account was configured to download off POP and then archive all messages (which moves it to the All Mail folder in Gmail).  If we recreate the local folder structure on Gmail and then use Thunderbird to move the local messages back up, I believe those messages will be duplicated?